# Merge two or more T in List<T> based on condition

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I have the below class:

```
public class FactoryOrder
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public int OrderNo { get; set; }        
    }
```

and collection holding the list of FactoryOrders

```
List<FactoryOrder>()
```

here is the sample data

```
FactoryOrder("Apple",20)
FactoryOrder("Orange",21)
FactoryOrder("WaterMelon",42)
FactoryOrder("JackFruit",51)
FactoryOrder("Grapes",71)
FactoryOrder("mango",72)
FactoryOrder("Cherry",73)
```

My requirement is to merge the Text of FactoryOrders where orderNo are in sequence and retain the lower orderNo for the merged FactoryOrder
 - so the resulting output will be

```
   FactoryOrder("Apple Orange",20) //Merged Apple and Orange and retained Lower OrderNo 20
    FactoryOrder("WaterMelon",42)
    FactoryOrder("JackFruit",51)
    FactoryOrder("Grapes mango Cherry",71)//Merged Grapes,Mango,cherry and retained Lower OrderNo 71
```

I am new to Linq so not sure how to go about this. Any help or pointers  would be appreciated

Comment: If your logic depends on consecutive items so heavily LINQ is not the easiest appoach. Use a simple loop. You could order them first with LINQ: `orders.Orderby(x => x.OrderNo )`

Comment: @TimSchmelter I don't even think there is a "sane" "pure" LINQ approach to this...

Comment: @xanatos: depends on what you call _pure_. There are LINQ extension methods on SO which group by adjacent items. But they are just hiding a lot of complex code. Like [this](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/GroupAdjacent.cs?r=fb6fc90407fc5af44485e9062d0c6f06606e1d10).

Comment: @xanatos: but even that implementation doesn't care about consecutive values of a property but consecutive items in the sequence with the same value in a property. So you're right, i don't know any implementation.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Clearly building a full program and hiding it behind LINQ isn't "pure" :-) But it is still a good solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As commented, if your logic depends on consecutive items so heavily LINQ is not the easiest appoach. Use a simple loop.

You could order them first with LINQ: `orders.OrderBy(x => x.OrderNo )`

```
var consecutiveOrdernoGroups = new List<List<FactoryOrder>> { new List<FactoryOrder>() };
FactoryOrder lastOrder = null;
foreach (FactoryOrder order in orders.OrderBy(o => o.OrderNo))
{
    if (lastOrder == null || lastOrder.OrderNo == order.OrderNo - 1)
        consecutiveOrdernoGroups.Last().Add(order);
    else
        consecutiveOrdernoGroups.Add(new List<FactoryOrder> { order });

    lastOrder = order;
}
```

Now you just need to build the list of `FactoryOrder` with the joined names for every group. This is where LINQ and `String.Join` can come in handy:

```
orders = consecutiveOrdernoGroups
    .Select(list => new FactoryOrder 
    { 
        Text    = String.Join(" ", list.Select(o => o.Text)),
        OrderNo = list.First().OrderNo // is the minimum number
    })
    .ToList();
```

[Result](http://fs1.directupload.net/images/150619/9bmfc7xk.jpg) with your sample:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this can be done using a single comprehensible LINQ expression. What would work is a simple enumeration:

```
    private static IEnumerable<FactoryOrder> Merge(IEnumerable<FactoryOrder> orders)
    {
        var enumerator = orders.OrderBy(x => x.OrderNo).GetEnumerator();

        FactoryOrder previousOrder = null;
        FactoryOrder mergedOrder = null;

        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            var current = enumerator.Current;

            if (mergedOrder == null)
            {
                mergedOrder = new FactoryOrder(current.Text, current.OrderNo);
            }
            else
            {
                if (current.OrderNo == previousOrder.OrderNo + 1)
                {
                    mergedOrder.Text += current.Text;
                }
                else
                {
                    yield return mergedOrder;
                    mergedOrder = new FactoryOrder(current.Text, current.OrderNo);
                }
            }

            previousOrder = current;
        }

        if (mergedOrder != null)
            yield return mergedOrder;
    }
```

This assumes `FactoryOrder` has a constructor accepting Text and OrderNo.

Answer (score 0):

Just coded a method, it's compact and quite good in terms of performance :

```
    static List<FactoryOrder> MergeValues(List<FactoryOrder> dirtyList)
    {            
        FactoryOrder[] temp1 = dirtyList.ToArray();
        int index = -1;
        for (int i = 1; i < temp1.Length; i++)
        {
            if (temp1[i].OrderNo - temp1[i - 1].OrderNo != 1) { index = -1; continue; }
            if(index == -1 ) index = dirtyList.IndexOf(temp1[i - 1]); 
            dirtyList[index].Text += " " + temp1[i].Text;                
            dirtyList.Remove(temp1[i]);
        }
        return dirtyList;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Linq implementation using side effects:

```
var groupId = 0;
var previous = Int32.MinValue;
var grouped = GetItems()
    .OrderBy(x => x.OrderNo)
    .Select(x =>
    {
        var @group = x.OrderNo != previous + 1 ? (groupId = x.OrderNo) : groupId;
        previous = x.OrderNo;
        return new
                {
                    GroupId = group,
                    Item = x
                };
    })
    .GroupBy(x => x.GroupId)
    .Select(x => new FactoryOrder(
       String.Join(" ", x.Select(y => y.Item.Text).ToArray()), 
       x.Key))
    .ToArray();

foreach (var item in grouped)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Text + "\t" + item.OrderNo);
}
```

output:

```
Apple Orange    20
WaterMelon  42
JackFruit   51
Grapes mango Cherry 71
```

Or, eliminate the side effects by using a generator extension method

```
public static class IEnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<IList<T>> MakeSets<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, T, bool> areInSameGroup)
    {
        var result = new List<T>();
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            if (!result.Any() || areInSameGroup(result[result.Count - 1], item))
            {
                result.Add(item);
                continue;
            }
            yield return result;
            result = new List<T> { item };
        }
        if (result.Any())
        {
            yield return result;
        }
    }
}
```

and your implementation becomes

```
var grouped = GetItems()
    .OrderBy(x => x.OrderNo)
    .MakeSets((prev, next) => next.OrderNo == prev.OrderNo + 1)
    .Select(x => new FactoryOrder(
        String.Join(" ", x.Select(y => y.Text).ToArray()),
        x.First().OrderNo))
    .ToList();

foreach (var item in grouped)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Text + "\t" + item.OrderNo);
}
```

The output is the same but the code is easier to follow and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

LINQ + sequential processing = [Aggregate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548651%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

It's not said though that using `Aggregate` is always the best option. Sequential processing in a `for(each)` loop usually makes for better readable code (see Tim's answer). Anyway, here's a pure LINQ solution.

It loops through the orders and first collects them in a dictionary having the first `Id` of consecutive orders as `Key`, and a collection of orders as `Value`. Then it produces a result using `string.Join`:

Class:

```
class FactoryOrder
{
    public FactoryOrder(int id, string name)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The program:

```
IEnumerable<FactoryOrder> orders =
    new[]
    {
        new FactoryOrder(20, "Apple"),
        new FactoryOrder(21, "Orange"),
        new FactoryOrder(22, "Pear"),
        new FactoryOrder(42, "WaterMelon"),
        new FactoryOrder(51, "JackFruit"),
        new FactoryOrder(71, "Grapes"),
        new FactoryOrder(72, "Mango"),
        new FactoryOrder(73, "Cherry"),
    };


var result = orders.OrderBy(t => t.Id).Aggregate(new Dictionary<int, List<FactoryOrder>>(),
    (dir, curr) =>
    {
        var prevId = dir.SelectMany(d => d.Value.Select(v => v.Id))
            .OrderBy(i => i).DefaultIfEmpty(-1)
            .LastOrDefault();
        var newKey = dir.Select(d => d.Key).OrderBy(i => i).LastOrDefault();
        if (prevId == -1 || curr.Id - prevId > 1)
        {
            newKey = curr.Id;
        }
        if (!dir.ContainsKey(newKey))
        {
            dir[newKey] = new List<FactoryOrder>();
        }
        dir[newKey].Add(curr);

        return dir;
    }, c => c)
    .Select(t => new
                 {
                     t.Key, 
                     Items = string.Join(" ", t.Value.Select(v => v.Name))
                 }).ToList();
```

As you see, it's not really straightforward what happens here, and chances are that it performs badly when there are "many" items, because the growing dictionary is accessed over and over again.

Which is a long-winded way to say: don't use Aggregate.